# set index.names on pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas, series

I want to set the following multiindexes to a pandas.Series . Currently, my indexes are [none, none], how can I change them?

```
Letters         bins
A              (2.212, 15.753]     4
               (15.753, 29.227]    1
B              (2.212, 15.753]     1
C              (2.212, 15.753]     1
               (15.753, 29.227]    3
               (29.227, 42.701]    2
D              (2.212, 15.753]     1
               (56.174, 69.648]    1
E              (56.174, 69.648]    1
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take some time to read [How to ask good questions?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, please try to create a [minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your own attempt and show it to us.

Comment: Please include sample(s) in text form that we can copy and paste for helping you, we don't want to type everything in... check out [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you mean to change the column names of a pandas DataFrame. You can use this, see if it helps:

```
df.set_index(['Letters', 'bins'], inplace=True)
```

Comment: i.e. change the column names before doing whatever operation (`groupby`, `stack` etc.) that applies the multiindex